# The plane cut by grids

Tags: st.statistics, plane-geometry

Suppose that one has an infinite two-dimensional regular grid of spacing one.  When laid on the plane it cuts it into unit squares.  Now take a second (identical) grid and place it with random shift and orientation on the plane, cutting the squares into smaller pieces.  Continue in this way with $n$ grids.

Can anything be said, statistically, of the areas of the pieces chopped up in this way? Does this problem have a name?

Comment: _Square Line Picking_ may be a useful search term: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquareLinePicking.html